# Three fixed divs and one flexible

Tags: css, html

I have a div with four other divs inside. The last three ones have fixed width but the first one needs to resize horizontally.

Here is the code on jsfiddle  with the CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/nsCzp/

I found some answers here but couldn't make it work.

```
<div _unidade="1" class="unidade">
    <div class="unidade nome media">Canoinhas</div>
    <div class="unidade orcado media">9944</div>
    <div class="unidade realizado media">8467</div>
    <div class="unidade link media">1/div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display:table` on the outer div, and `display:table-cell` on the inner ones. (*and remove the floats completely*)

```
.unidade {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-shadow: 0 0;

    display:table;
    width:100%;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.unidade .unidade{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nsCzp/2/

Comment: This does not maintain the fixed widths of the last three divs.

Comment: actually if you add .unidade.nome {width:auto;} then it works.

Comment: Thanks! It worked nice! @andi the last three divs have their widths maintened.